# Invalid Header Signature Error on sending logs to Cribl using a Splunk Universal Forwarder

Tags: logging, splunk, forward

I am new to Cribl Stream and I am exploring the Cribl Stream use cases. I tried to forward some logs directly to Cribl Stream using a Universal Forwarder. I used a Splunk TCP source with the default configuration. On the splunk forwarder end, the output configuration is as follows:

`[tcpout] disabled = false defaultGroup = cribl`

`[tcpout:cribl] server = in.xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx.cribl.cloud:9997 sendCookedData = false negotiateProtocolLevel = 0`

I am getting the following error on Cribl:

`Invalid header signature=11-15-2022 06:23:09.642 +0000 INFO  AutoLoadBalancedConnectionStrategy [3477 TcpOutEloop] - Connected to idx=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9997`

Please let me know where I am going wrong with this.

I am expecting the universal forwarder to forward the logs to Cribl and then to a destination that I've configured. The same forwarder is forwarding the logs to a Splunk enterprise version.